# Why $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2^2)^{\sqrt n}}{(1+(10)^{-2^2})^n}$ has no limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2^2)^{\sqrt n}}{(1+(10)^{-2^2})^n}$

I looked it up in the wolfram and my intuition tells me that this expression has no limit, but every step I did doesn't lead me to the solution.

Comment: Why are you sure the limit doesn't exist? For integer $n$, the denominator will outrace the numerator...

Comment: Here's another hint: take the logarithm of the expression and simplify it. If you know $\log (A_n) \to L$ as $n\to\infty$ (for $L$ an extended real), what can you infer about the behavior of $A_n$?

Comment: Are you sure this was supposed to be the limit? You haven't lost anything on Latex?

Comment: Why to write $2^2$ instead of $4$?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that for $n$ big enough we have

$$5<(1+10^{-4})^\sqrt{n}$$
so
$$5^{\sqrt{n}}<(1+10^{-4})^n $$
and then
$$\frac{4^{\sqrt n}}{(1+10^{-4})^n} <\frac{4^{\sqrt n}}{5^{\sqrt{n}}}=\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{\sqrt n} \to 0$$

Comment: Nice way. I enjoyed the *"big enough"*. $\to +1$

Answer (score 0):

Why do you come to that conclusion? You are looking at
$$ \frac{4^\sqrt{n}}{(1+10^{-4})^n}$$

Now notice that $4>1$ and $1+10^{-4}>1$, so both denominator and numerator are growing, but as $\sqrt n$ grows much slower than $n$ the numerator will also grow slower than the denominator, so the whole thing goes to $0$.

To see this simply apply a logarithm (to get rid of the different bases):

$$\log \ldots = \log(4) \sqrt{n} - \log(1+10^{-4})n $$
Obviously this goes to $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.